# How would I overload method in an interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface

if I have this interface

```
public interface someInterface {
  // method 1
  public String getValue(String arg1);
  // method 2
  public String getValue(String arg1, String arg2);
}
```

I want to be able to pass in 1 or 2 string to the getValue method without having to override both in each implementing class.

```
public class SomeClass1 impelments someInterface 
{
 @Override
 public String getValue(String arg1);
}

public class SomeClass2 implements someInterface 
{
 @Override
 public String getValue(String arg1, String arg2);
}
```

this won't work because SomeClass1 needs to implement method 2 and SomeClass2 needs to implement method 1.

Am I stuck doing this?

```
public interface someInterface2 {
  public String getValue(String... args);
}

public class SomeClass3 implements someInterface2 
{
  @Override
  public String getValue(String... args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    // code
  }
}

public class SomeClass4 implements someInterface2
{
  @Override
  public String getValue(String... args) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      throw IllegalArgumentException();
     }
    // code
  }
}

someInterface2 someClass3 = new SomeClass3();
someInterface2 someClass4 = new SomeClass4();
String test1 = someClass3.getValue("String 1");
String test2 = someClass4.getValue("String 1, "String 2");
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should use 2 interfaces.

Comment: Make your classes `abstract`. Otherwise, your classes **must** implement both methods of the interface. Due to the simplicity of the example, separate it in two interfaces would not be of any help.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you passed in a single string and the class had only implemented the two-parameter method, or vice versa?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  The situation you're describing smells of a code design problem.

Comment: Your two classes should behave differently, so they shouldn't implement the same interface (even though the names of their methods might be identical, their contract is not). Use two interfaces, as Sotirios suggested.

Comment: I want to treat the two classes the same. They both store an internal lookup table, one being a map and the other being a Guava Table. I want the getValue method to return a result regardless of how its being looked up. The only difference is the map needs 1 param while the Guava Table needs two param.

Comment: If you need to know which of the implementations you have, in order to call the method properly, you can as well just add the right method in each class, and remove it from the interface completely.

Comment: You can't "treat two classes the same" in the way you're trying to do when you can't call the same methods on both classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An interface serves as a *contract* for the users of that interface: you specify what methods are available (in *all* implementations) and how they are called. If two implementations of an interface need a different method, then that method should *not* be part of the interface:

```
public interface Lookup {
}

public class MapLookup implements Lookup {
    public String getValue(String key) {
        //...
    }
}

public class GuavaLookup implements Lookup {
    public String getValue(String row, String column) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In your program, you will know which implementation you use, so you can simply call the right function:

```
public class Program {
    private Lookup lookup = new MapLookup();

    public void printLookup(String key) {
        // I hardcoded lookup to be of type MapLookup, so I can cast:
        System.out.println(((MapLookup)lookup).getValue(key));
    }
}
```

**Alternative approach**

If your class `Program` is more generic and uses dependency injections, you may not know which implementation you have. Then, I would make a new interface `Key`, which can be either type of key:

```
public interface Lookup {
    // ...

    public String getValue(Key key);
}

public interface Key {
}

public MapKey implements Key {
    private String key;
    // ...
}

public GuavaKey implements Key {
    private String row, column;
    // ...
}
```

The dependency injection in your program might come from some factory implementation. Since you cannot know which type of lookup you use, you need a single contract for `getValue`.

```
public interface Factory {
    public Lookup getLookup();
    public Key getKey();
}

public class Program {
    private Lookup lookup;

    public Program(Factory factory) {
        lookup = factory.getLookup();
    }

    public void printLookup(Factory factory) {      
        System.out.println((lookup.getValue(factory.getKey()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks both solutions are helpful

Comment: Don't you think Visitor pattern violates this then?

Comment: @zgulser can you elaborate?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele I totally got you wrong for some reason. Sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 12):

As of Java 8, you can have an interface provide an implementation of a method, through the use of the [default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) keyword. Therefore a new solution would be to provide a default implementation of both methods which maybe throws an exception, then derive the actual implementation from the default interface.

Anyways here is how you can do this:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    // method 1
    default String getValue(String arg1) {
        // you decide what happens with this default implementation
    }

    // method 2
    default String getValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
        // you decide what happens with this default implementation
    }
}
```

Finally, make the classes override the correct methods

```
public class SomeClass1 implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public String getValue(String arg1) {
        return arg1;
    }
}

public class SomeClass2 implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public String getValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
        return arg1 + " " + arg2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution (not very elegant) might look loke this:

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
   public String getValue(String arg1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
   public String getValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
}

public class SomeClass1 extends SomeClass {
   public String getValue(String arg1) {
      // return sth
   }
}

public class SomeClass2 extends SomeClass {
   public String getValue(String arg1, String arg2) {
      // return sth
   }
}
```

However there's a drawback - SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 can't inherit directly other class.

Comment: This is actually very close to the solution I posted. It's like you could see into the future...

Comment: Seems reasonable, and yet empty methods that throw exceptions are a violation of LSP ( Liskov Substitution Principle.)   - They are almost like contract violations, and surprise your API users. Have fun trying to add an item to a list you get from Arrays.asList and see how it feels.

Answer (score 0):

If the second value can be considered optional in a sense and you always have the 2 arguments when calling you could create a wrapper class which implements the 2 parameter interface passing the 1 parameter implementation as a constructor parameter and calling that in the method, e.g. something like this:

```
interface A{
  method1(P1)
}

interface B{
  method2(P1, P2)
}

class Wrap implements B{
  Wrap(A impl)

  override method2(P1, P2){
    call impl.method1(P1)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    default void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    /**
     * Note the this overloads {@link SomeInterface#print(String)}, 
     * not overrides it!
     */
    public void print(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```