# Overloading Java Method from Inherited Interface

Tags: java, overloading

Question:

I have the following:

```
interface A 
{
    int MethodA(int x, int y);
}
```

and

```
interface B extends A
{
    //This is meant to overload MethodA
    int MethodA(int x, int y, int z);
}
```

The problem comes when I try to implement interface B, and run the method in main.

```
class Foo implements B
{
    //For interface B
    public int MethodA(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        //Actual implementation
    }

    //For interface A
    public int MethodA(int x, int y)
    {
        //Actual implementation
    }
}

public static void main(String[] s)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    //Problem occurs here
    foo.MethodA(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Eclipse will complain and say that "The method MethodA(int, int, int) in the type A is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)."

But why? I've already implemented interface B. Shouldn't MethodA(int, int, int) have overload MethodA(int, int), making MethodA able to accept three integers as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843645/how-would-i-overload-method-in-an-interface

Comment: Works for me in Java 7, once of course I've corrected all the compilation mistakes in the given code (return type, public modifier, argument names)

Comment: This is not Java code. This is plain text.

Comment: The alleged compile error here seems inapplicable. Maybe the line is mistyped and should read:  A foo = new Foo();

Answer (score 0):

The above looks a little confused.

You need to specify your return types, specify names for each argument (even in the interface) and declare the implemented methods as public eg.

```
   public int MethodA(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        //Actual implementation e.g.
        return 0;
    }
```

Your static `main()` method has to reside within a class (e.g. the `Foo` class above), and finally call the method with real arguments.

Once you've done that, then all should be good. You can certainly provide overloading as in the above. You just need to resolve the more basic issues first. I would get a very basic single method going, and then enhance from there in order to get something working.

Comment: `Once you've done that, then all should be good`. Not true. What about `foo.MethodA(int, int, int);`?

Comment: I missed that. Thank you. There's just *so* much at issue here

Comment: Yes. It gives me a headache to see such questions on stackoverflow. But if they are not answered, then the quality of questions will only get worse.

Comment: Could the downvoter please provide a reason or rescind ?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but the answer only covered the issue with return type but missed the method arguments and method call issues completely in it's first few versions.