# How would I write an interface for a metric for a similarity between any two objects?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I want to create a class `Similarity` that computes a similarity matrix based on a user's choice of similarity:

- Gaussian
- Cosine
- Euclidean distance
- Custom engineered similarities for any object.

So for the first 3 use cases, I can see the path forward (psuedocode):

```java
public interface Metric {
    public abstract double compute(double[] x1, double[] x2);
}

public GaussianSimilarity implements Metric {
    public double compute(double[] x1, double[] x2) {
        // some math 
        return similarity;
    }
}

SimilarityMatrix sim = new SimilarityMatrix(new GuassianSimilarity());
double[][] similarityArray = sim.fit(someData);
```

However, what if people want to create a similarity matrix based on a set of custom objects, rather than on numeric data? Is there a way to keep one common interface that would work on numbers, lists/arrays of numbers PLUS arbitrary objects?

```
public interface Metric {
    public abstract double compute(Thing one, Thing two);
}
```

What would the signature of `compute` look like in this case?

Comment: Look into java generics, there should be a lot of examples.

Comment: Take a look at this question, which covers method overloading in an interface, look at the second answer specifically, which utilizes the default keyword: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843645/how-would-i-overload-method-in-an-interface/15844172